# No cerrar modal Bootstrap si el formulario de registro, tiene un error

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5

Tengo un formulario de registro en Bootstrap, pero si algún campo tiene un error el mismo se cierra pero mantiene la información, al volver hacer clic en el botón registrar se muestran los datos y el error.

No sé cómo mantener abierto el formulario en caso que contenga error, para que el usuario sepa que debe corregirlo.

-- Botón --

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="btn btn-purple" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#registerModal" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
</li>
```

-- Modal --

```
<!-- Register Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="registerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="px-5" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
            @csrf

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" placeholder="{{ __('Username') }}" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autocomplete="username" autofocus>

                    @error('name')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" placeholder="{{ __('Password') }}" required autocomplete="new-password">

                    @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('Confirm Password') }}" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple w-100">
                        {{ __('Register') }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por un momento pensé que me habia equivocado en mi anterior comentario, pero mirándolo bien no era asi. Por lo tanto te lo repito. Dado que las validaciones las realizas desde el servidor la forma más idónea de realizar lo que deseas es enviando el formulario via ajax y manejar su respuesta acorde con lo esperado. Si todos los campos son correctos entonces mandar cerrar al modal con javascript, y en caso de que haya uno incorrecto repintar todo el modal con el formulario con los errores marcados que te llega del servidor.

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba evualuando en este momento usar livewire ya que trabajo con Laravel, eso no te lo comenté.

Comment: Ni idea, no toco laravel ni livewire, lo siento, en eso no puedo aconsejarte. Te he agregado la etiqueta de Laravel en tu pregunta para darle también esa visibilidad. Suerte!

Comment: La solución seria hacerlo en una solicitud por ajax, así se espera la respuesta, del cuál decides ocultar o no el modal, si quieres hacerlo con el formulario tradicional deberías devolver desde el controlador a la misma vista con el modal desplegado y colocando en las inputs los datos que se enviaron.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos